# Turn a SQL query to custom format XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I need to query SQL, choose certain columns, then transpose that into XML. The SQL headings and XML headings are not the same.

What I am looking for is some direction. I know how to query SQL and get results in $results, but is that the best format? Do I need to make a powershell object?

XML needs to look like:

```
<incident>
    <incidentid></incidentid>
    <email></email>
    <dtclosed></dtclosed>
    <firstname></firstname>
    <lastname></lastname>
    <desc></desc>
</incident>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
CREATE TABLE Test_Table(incidentid INT, email VARCHAR(100),dtclosed DATE
, firstname VARCHAR(100), lastname VARCHAR(100), [DESC] VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO Test_Table VALUES
(1, 'aaa@aol.com',GETDATE(), 'firstname 1', 'lastname 1', 'Desc 1'),
(2, 'bbb@aol.com',GETDATE(), 'firstname 2', 'lastname 2', 'Desc 2')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT incidentid
      ,email
      ,dtclosed
      ,firstname
      ,lastname
      ,[DESC]
FROM Test_Table
FOR XML PATH('incident'), ELEMENTS
```

You can also add `ROOT('incidents')` to the above query to make it a well formatted XML Document.

**Result Set**

```
<incident>
  <incidentid>1</incidentid>
  <email>aaa@aol.com</email>
  <dtclosed>2014-03-10</dtclosed>
  <firstname>firstname 1</firstname>
  <lastname>lastname 1</lastname>
  <DESC>Desc 1</DESC>
</incident>
<incident>
  <incidentid>2</incidentid>
  <email>bbb@aol.com</email>
  <dtclosed>2014-03-10</dtclosed>
  <firstname>firstname 2</firstname>
  <lastname>lastname 2</lastname>
  <DESC>Desc 2</DESC>
</incident>
```

Comment: Thank you for that! Do you know the correct way in powershell to add a root element to this? <CSI><incidents></></CSI>?

Comment: just add `,ROOT('CSI')` at the end of the query. this should do the job for you. and if it helped please accept the answer thank you.